# How do I get a thumbnail of a file (png, jpg, pdf, etc.)?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a simple file manager as a learning project. And I have a question how can I get the thumbnail of a file to display it in the RecyclerView list?

I'm also interested in whether `java.io.File` has a unique ID? I need to cache files in the local storage and compare which ones have changed since the app was last launched.

Comment: What do you consider to be 'the thumbnail of a file'? A file icon? I understand thumbnail of an image file.

Comment: Then what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @KJ Do I understand correctly that for a thumbnail image I can just use Glide/Coil and decrease the resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like *Glide* anyway, that's the [standard recommendation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) and it will automatically scale images to fit your `ImageView`s, run it concurrently so it's not blocking the main thread, do caching etc.

This is especially important for things like `RecyclerView`s where you might be scrolling through a lot of images quickly - not only does it need to be performant, you need to make sure old requests for a given `ViewHolder` are cancelled so it doesn't end up displaying the wrong image for the current item (since `ViewHolder`s are reused when scrolling). Libraries like *Glide* handle this for you!

In some cases where you're using `Intent`s to fetch images, you'll get a thumbnail `Bitmap` in the result `Intent` ([example](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ImageCapture)) while the actual image is accessed via a provided URL. So in those cases, that might be a useful way to display a thumbnail (not in your case, just mentioning it as a good thing to know! Just use Glide etc.)

---

Your other question is a different one. I'm not sure if `File` gives you access to a specific reference determined by the filesystem, but even if it did that wouldn't tell you if that file object had changed. You can register a path with a [WatchService](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/WatchService) to watch for changes, but that only works while your app is running obviously.

To look for changes since the app was last run, you'd have to store some state and compare it to the current state. Maybe mapping `Path#hashCode` to `File#lastModified`, and looking for changes to that (as well as new files without a path entry, and maybe path entries with no corresponding file). Or you could store checksums for files, using *MD5* or something.

You'd probably want to handle this in a repository or something. So your app requests the list of files for a particular directory from the repo, and that handles fetching them from disk, loading the old state, comparing the files and sticking them in a data structure (e.g. a data class that holds the path, updated status etc), updating the stored state, and firing off the data to the requester.

If you want to know more about the repository pattern, have a look at this guide: [Data layer](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/data-layer). The idea is your list view requests data for a particular directory, puts in a request from a repo component, and gets the data delivered later (usually getting a `Flow` that's handled in a coroutine). Accessing the disk is quite heavy, which is why it needs to be done concurrently (Glide takes care of this for you, which is why it's nice, but it's only for loading images!)

Comment: Omitted: How does one get a thumbnail of a pdf, doc,..

Comment: @blackapps I did forget to mention it, but any kind of non-image resource that Glide can't decode (or unhandled image formats) will require a custom decoder, probably involving a library that can handle that file type. Exactly how you extract an image representation from an arbitrary file is gonna depend on the file type and what's available to you, e.g. out-of-the-box functionality in Glide, thumbnails stored in the file format itself, available libraries that can generate a thumbnail, etc. You have to decide what you want to handle specifically